# É possível adicionar mais de um item a uma lista de uma só vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber se é possivel adicionar mais de um elemento a uma lista, por exemplo:

```
a=[]
a.append('abóbora', 'banana', 'maçã')
```

ou será necessário usar três linhas, por exemplo:

```
a=[]
a.append('abóbora')
a.append('banana')
a.append('maçã')
```

me respondam, por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o método `.append` você não conseguirá colocar uma sequência de valores dentro de uma lista. O método correto para realizar a entrada de uma sequência  é o `.extend`, logo ficará assim:

```
lista = []
lista.extend(('abóbora', 'banana', 'maçã'))
print(lista)
```

saída:

```
['abóbora', 'banana', 'maçã']
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o operador `+=` para concatenar uma lista em outra:

```
a = []
a += ['abóbora', 'banana', 'maçã']
print(a)
```

Saída:

```
['abóbora', 'banana', 'maçã']
```